# Popup links inside apps

Tags: browser, hyperlinks

When I try to open links inside apps, eg Inbox AliExpress Whatsapp, instead of opening up them in chrome,  it pops up some windows without javascript, and I cannot use it, how can I disable it?[image]

Comment: Can you show how it looks when WhatsApp is opened?

Comment: It looks the same as the picture, its not a pop up that I didnt want, its just the link I've wanted to open, but instead it opens up here, instead of chrome, it started happening after upgrading to nexus 5x

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the data of those apps.

Does this happen in every app? If so, then it might be a sign of malware infection.

If clearing app data doesn't help, try installing some antivirus software and do a full system scan.

Also, try switching off Internet or mobile data and opening whatsapp. If problem continues, it indicates a malware or virus. If it stops, it might be either a malware or adware. Try this:

Clear cache from settings. **Turn off mobile data**. Switch off phone and switch it on again. **Keeping mobile data off**, and open the app, or whatsapp specifically, and then all other such apps.

If pop up continues even after this, then it's a malware or virus problem. If it stops, but starts once you turn on mobile data, it's probably an adware.

In any case, a good antivirus like QuickHeal will get you rid of both of these.

Comment: Well it cant be a malware, it started opening links in these pop ups after upgrading to 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Disable the app called Setup Wizard.

Settings > Apps > All Apps > Select 'Show system apps' in the menu > Find Setup Wizard, tap it and disable it. Done.